# How to create ASP.NET Core Web API controller method with similar but different parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a simple Web API with ASP.NET Core. I have the following API:

- GET /api/messages - get all messages
- GET /api/messages/{id} - get a message by id
- POST /api/messages - add a new message
- PUT /api/messages/{id} - update an existing message
- DELETE /api/messages/{id} - delete a message

Now, I want another API to get all messages by message owner's name.

**What I tried**:

I tried to create this API, but it doesn't work because it conflicts with GET /api/messages/{id}:

- GET /api/messages/{name} <- (doesn't work due to conflicting API)

  ```
  // GET: api/messages/{name}
  [HttpGet("{name}")]
  public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesByName(string name)
  {
      return _repository.GetMessages().Where(m => m.Owner == name);
  }
  ```

Here is my Message model **Message.cs**:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Messages controller **MessagesController.cs**:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MessagesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMessageRepository _repository;

    public MessagesController(IMessageRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: api/messages
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Message> Get()
    {
        return _repository.GetMessages();
    }

    // GET api/messages/{id}
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetMessage")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var message = _repository.GetMessage(id);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(message);
    }

    // POST api/messages
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _repository.AddMessage(message);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetMessage", new { id = message.Id }, message);

    }

    // PUT api/messages/{id}
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(long id, [FromBody]Message message)
    {
        if (message == null || message.Id != id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var messageToUpdate = _repository.GetMessage(id);
        if (messageToUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        messageToUpdate.Owner = message.Owner;
        messageToUpdate.Text = message.Text;

        _repository.UpdateMessage(messageToUpdate);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }

    // DELETE api/messages/{id}
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(long id)
    {
        var message = _repository.GetMessage(id);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        _repository.RemoveMessage(id);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

**Question**:

How can I create an API method to get all messages by message owner's name?

Ideally, I would like the API to look like GET /api/messages/{name}, but don't think its possible since it conflicts with GET /api/messages/{id}.

I'm thinking of creating the API like this, but I'm not sure how.

- GET /api/messages/name/{name} <- (or something along that line)

**Solution**:

To have GET /api/messages/{name} working without conflicting with GET /api/messages/{id}, change attribute `[HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetMessage")]` to `[HttpGet("{id:long}", Name="GetMessage")]` for `public IActionResult GetById(long id)` method.

To also have GET /api/messages/name/{name} working, add `[Route("name/{name}")]` attribute to `public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesByName(string name)` method.

Comment: An option would be /api/users/{id}/messages or /api/messages?owner=...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put parameter type in route, so your code method should be look like that:

```
 // GET api/messages/{id}
    [HttpGet("{id:long}", Name = "GetMessage")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var message = _repository.GetMessage(id);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(message);
    }
```

I think, web api is ignoring parameters types in routes if they are not typed explicitly, so in your example it has two routes like this: `api/messages/{object}` and when you put explicit type, they are like this: `api/messages/{object}` and `api/messages/{long}`

Comment: I'm now getting the following exception `System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'name' - 'string' on the route 'api/Messages/{name:string}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.`

Comment: my fault - try to put explicit type only in `GetById` method

Comment: This is because attribute routing has not `string` constraint as your exception showed, but `long` is perfectly acceptable. I have updated answer too.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution I was looking for and also mentioning attribute routing.